# I have just created the first component inside a newly build React app and am getting warning messages about circular dependecies

Tags: reactjs

I have just created a new React app using `npx react app project-name`.
When I run `npm start`, the error messages seen below are logged, then it eventually says that it compiled successfully and is running.

There is a second issue, perhaps it is a symptom of the same problem. I created the first component `/src/components/Employee.js`:

```js
function Employee() {
    return <h3>This is an Employee</h3>;
}
export default Employee;
```

When I import it, it returns and error `error  'React' must be in scope when using JSX`

I am trying to learn React, so not sure where to start with regards to debugging. NPM version - 9.5.1, node version 18.16.0

[image: Circular dependency warnings]

Comment: Do you have `import React from 'react'` in your Employee.js file?  Also, do you get the same result if you rename Employee.js to Employee.jsx?

Comment: A circular dependency error occurs when you import 2 files into each other—pasting a screenshot of Employee.js can help more to suggest something to you